# How do I show errors when form properties are objects?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a form with fields for bankAccount input.

Field: bankAccount.currency
Field: bankAccount.bank
Field: name

```
bankAccount {
    currency?: string;
    bank?: string;
}
```

I want to show the errors to the user

```
<div *ngFor="let error of errors">
  {{ error }}
</div>
```

This will give me the error for the name alright but when the bankAccount.currency field errors I get `bank account: 0 [object Object]`.

How do I get the content of the `[object Object]`?

Comment: what are you trying to show there from the object?

Comment: The `[object Object]` part holds the actual error info strings. FYI I will rewrite the form to use validators

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, Angular provides a `ValidationErrors` interface:

```js
/**
 * An object containing any errors generated by failing validation,
 * or null if there are no errors.
 */
readonly errors: ValidationErrors | null;
```

Let's say you added a `required` validator on a form control and the validation fails, simply check for the occurance of `errors.required`. If the property exists, the validation failed and you can display feedback to the client.

A more complete solution would be to keep track of a list of validation messages:

```js
export const ValidationMessages = {
  required: 'Field is required',
  ...
}
```

Then create a helper method to show the (first) validation message:

```js
showError(errors: ValidationErrors): string | null {
  const key = Object.keys(errors)[0];

  return ValidationMessages[key] || 'Field is invalid';
}
```

... and use it in your template: `showError(errors)`

Protip: use the [json pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe) convert an object to JSON format (i.e. `{{ errors | json}}`.

Comment: Thx I will look into this. The errors are not from Angular validators though, they are from the backend validation so I believe this does not change anything.

Comment: Thx again. I will switch to validators

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the object into a string for the output.

```
JSON.stringify(error)
```

Comment: Thx but I was probably not clear enough. It is not the error that is an object (this is the exact error: `bank account: 0 [object Object]`) it is the additional message inside the object I want to make human readable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**`json`**](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe) pipe to stringify the value of the object:

```
<div *ngFor="let error of errors">
  {{ error | json }}
</div>
```

With this, you would be able to determine the structure of the `error` object in the `errors` array.

You would then want to display an appropriate error message using the properties in the `error` object.

Comment: Thx but I was probably not clear enough. It is not the error that is an object (this is the exact error: `bank account: 0 [object Object]`) it is the additional message inside the object I want to make human readable. (Sorry for the cut and paste answer)

Answer (score 0):

you can just access the properties you're trying to show:

```
<div *ngFor="let error of errors">
  Currency: {{ error.currency }}, Bank: {{ error.bank }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thx but what you cannot see in my question is that I have around 100 fields so this is unfortunately not viable.

Comment: At a certain point you have to map the fields into a human readable format. A computer isn’t going to magically do it for you. Clarify your goals here

Comment: I'm sorry the information i supplied was not to your satisfaction. I will do my best to improve that next time.
I will rewrite the form to use Angular validators, FYI